# Typescript dynamic import do not crash/allow compilation on non existing file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dynamic-import

Well I have a system where I have a local input file which has some extra information regarding login etc. Obviously that file isn't in git so it won't be visible for the public when building or even developing on another pc.

I've tried making it hence a dynamic import that is guarded an a try-catch statement, if the file would be there it should just execute on page launch. Otherwise it shouldn't.

So in `app.tsx` under the main component there is this:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  async function loader() {
    if (!process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
      try {
        //@ts-ignore
        const data = await import('./local/input_data');
        //@ts-ignore
        if (data['userLoginData']) {
          //@ts-ignore
          await AuthStoreCtx.authStore?.doLogin({username: data.userLoginData.username, password: data.userLoginData.password});
          if (!AuthStoreCtx.authStore?.loginFailed) {
            console.log("AUTO LOGIN SUCCEEDS");
          } else {
            console.log("AUTO LOGIN FAILED");
          }
          setUser(AuthStoreCtx.authStore?.user);
        }

      } catch (err) {
        console.log("AUTO LOGIN FAIL")
      }
    } else {
      console.log('production')
    }
  }
  if (authStore) {
    loader().then(() => {

    });
  }
}, [authStore]);
```

However this gives the following error:

> Module not found: Error: ...

That is no surprise, but what's surprising is that the error isn't caught by the catch statement (or later by the `.catch()` outside the promise). How would I do such a thing?

Comment: You don't see `AUTO LOGIN FAIL`? (It wouldn't surprise me to *also* see a console message about a failed module import, but you should see your `catch` clause run.) `import` returns a promise (as you know), there's nothing special that makes it bypass standard rejection handling (via `try` and `await`, in your case). Perhaps you're using a bundler with slightly dodgy handling of this? No native handling in a browser should do that.

Comment: Well it's create react app "build" process that fails when producing a production build.

Comment: Okay, so you need to look at the bundler you're using (Webpack in CRA if I recall correctly). They often have additional requirements on dynamic import that aren't in the spec.